# Get Previous and Next Row from First & Last Row output Respectively

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to achieve the following output

| TABLE_NAME | MONTH |
| --- | --- |
| vbSuccessfulCDR_598 | 2019-02 |
| vbSuccessfulCDR_599 | 2019-03 |
| vbSuccessfulCDR_600 | 2019-04 |
| vbSuccessfulCDR_601 | 2019-05 |
| vbSuccessfulCDR_602 | 2019-06 |

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME,
       SUBSTRING(TIMESTAMPADD(MONTH,
                    CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(TABLE_NAME, '_', -1) AS UNSIGNED) - 595,
                    '2018-11-01'),1, 7) AS MONTH
                        
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'vbSuccessfulCDR_%'
AND SUBSTRING(TIMESTAMPADD(MONTH,
                    CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(TABLE_NAME, '_', -1) AS UNSIGNED) - 595,
                    '2018-11-01'),1, 7) BETWEEN '2019-03' AND '2019-05';
```

My Query is giving the following output:

| TABLE_NAME | MONTH |
| --- | --- |
| vbSuccessfulCDR_599 | 2019-03 |
| vbSuccessfulCDR_600 | 2019-04 |
| vbSuccessfulCDR_601 | 2019-05 |

**Can anyone suggest how can I get the previous and next row in the output**

Comment: Convert year-month range borders to postfix values (table names). Using them obtain the tables names which are "previous and next" (`WHERE tablename < name_with_lower_bound ORDER BY tablename DESC LIMIT 1` and the same for upper bound). Use these values in BETWEEN.

Comment: @Akina Can you please elaborate, Don't understand how to add them.

Comment: In the subquery you calculate that `'2019-03'` matches the postfix `599` and the tablename `vbSuccessfulCDR_599`. You query `SELECT tablename FROM .. WHERE .. AND table_name < 'vbSuccessfulCDR_599' ORDER BY table_name DESC LIMIT 1` and receive `'vbSuccessfulCDR_598'`. The same for upper bound gives `'vbSuccessfulCDR_601'`. Now you use `WHERE table_name BETWEEN 'vbSuccessfulCDR_598' AND 'vbSuccessfulCDR_601'` in your query. Of course you use not values but subqueries outputs.